# QGIS world imagery does not repeat itself

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

Is it possible to make raster imagery from a service like OSM repeat itself like google maps does? I want to create a map of the world that shows Australia at the center, but the imagery stops at new zealand? It doesnt repeat the imagery from the other side of the dateline. I imagine this is just a tick box somewhere, any ideas. (i know i could do this manually by exporting and joining, but i am more curious if this is possible in qgis in a more dynamic way)

[image]

Comment: Im using Open layers plugin to bring in imagery..and qgis 2.16

Comment: Thats interesting. Have you set the CRS as EPSG:3857? Also what version of QGIS are you using? I'm in 2.16.1 and layers from the openlayers plugin draw continuously when I load them in a fresh project.

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers use EPSG: 3857 which is WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator. OpenLayers plugin does not display only Google map layer without any other vector/raster layer. In order to display the map correctly you need to add one vector layer at least, then you can turn off that layer, and make sure the CRS used to display Google map layer is EPSG: 3857 which is WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator in the lower left window of QGIS, as you can see below:

[image]

The result in the map composer is as follows:

[image]

Google map uses continuous tiles by default, but in case of OSM, it is not, and open layers cannot provide an option to adjust the tiles to repeat itself again.

Another option is that you can use QuickMapServices Plugin. Although it does not provide an option for the tiles to repeat again, but you can change the project as a workaround to something like EPSG: 53003 'Sphere_Miller_Cylindrical', but there is gap between the tiles when it is start to repeat itself, as you can see below:

[image]